# Turn List to Key-Value Dictionary Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How can I convert a list that has entries like `"MAX_PAYLOAD NVARCHAR(5)"` to a dictionary that contains key value pairs like `"MAX_PAYLOAD" : "NVARCHAR(5)"` ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this string is representative of what you're going to see, you might be able to simply split on the space in the middle to create a tuple, then create a dictionary from those tuples.

```
lines = [
    "MAX_PAYLOAD NVARCHAR(5)",
    "MIN_PAYLOAD NVARCHAR(4)",
]
broken_lines = [line.split(maxsplit=1) for line in lines]
assert dict(broken_lines) == {'MAX_PAYLOAD': 'NVARCHAR(5)', 'MIN_PAYLOAD': 'NVARCHAR(4)'}
```

If you might have other whitespaces or something, figure out a different splitting function that'll work for you.